# Cannot assign variable in Tensorflow-Lite: "incompatible with expected resource"

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to compile a stateful graph in TensorFlow-lite.  I'm on **tensorflow 2.8.1**.  As an example below, I've used cumulative sum:

```
    @dataclass
    class CumulativeSum:
        cumsum: tf.Variable = field(default_factory=lambda: tf.Variable(initial_value=0., dtype=tf.float64))

        def add(self, x):
            self.cumsum.assign(self.cumsum + x)
            return self.cumsum.value()
```

But when I try to convert it to a tf-lite model ...

```
    # Make concrete function
    cumsummer = CumulativeSum()
    concrete_func = tf.function(
        input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float64)],
    )(cumsummer.add).get_concrete_function()

    # Check that concrete function works
    assert [concrete_func(float(x)) for x in range(4)] == [0, 1, 3, 6]

    # Save tflite model
    converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_concrete_functions([concrete_func])
    converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS, tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS]  # enable TensorFlow Lite ops.]
    serialized_model = converter.convert()
    # ^^^ ABOVE LINE THROWS:
    #   ValueError: Input 0 of node AssignVariableOp was passed double from ReadVariableOp/resource:0 incompatible with expected resource.
```

... I get the error

```
ValueError: Input 0 of node AssignVariableOp was passed double from ReadVariableOp/resource:0 incompatible with expected resource.
```

Full test code to reproduce this is in this colab notebook:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KPjHhlCMVs2oFxodrFAO7YcPrfBADC2k?usp=sharing

Are stateful graphs expected to work at all in TFLite?

Comment: For the record, I've tried `converter.experimental_enable_resource_variables = True` - no dice.

Answer (score 0):

**Figured it out**.  The key was in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lite/TFLiteConverter) for the `TFLiteConverter.experimental_enable_resource_variables`.

```
    experimental_enable_resource_variables: Experimental flag, subject to
      change. Enables resource variables to be converted by this converter. This
      is only allowed if from_saved_model interface is used. (default False)
```

I needed to create the model with `tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)` for the variable assignment to work.

This means

1. Making the class a subclass of `tf.Module`, as in `class CumulativeSum(tf.Module)`
2. Saving the model:

```
    # Save tflite model
    cumsummer = CumulativeSum()  # Re-instantiate so that we start from blank state
    concrete_func = tf.function(
        input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float64)],
    )(cumsummer.add).get_concrete_function()
    saved_model_dir = os.path.expanduser('~/Downloads/test_save_model')
    tf.saved_model.save(obj=cumsummer, export_dir=saved_model_dir, signatures={"add": concrete_func})
```

3. Loading the converter with `converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)`

Colab notebook with full working example:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Ud3lcyweOIeHRUgsoqr7-kBxndZSSBcH?usp=sharing

---

And [here is another colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1uPs-jCjL2TCaf8_MZ-yxRG3suFxEkAkm?usp=sharing) with useful helper functions to help save and load the model, so the full code is just

```
@dataclass
class CumulativeSum(tf.Module):
    cumsum: tf.Variable = field(default_factory=lambda: tf.Variable(initial_value=0., dtype=tf.float64))

    def add(self, x):
        self.cumsum.assign(self.cumsum + x)
        return self.cumsum.value()

cumsummer = CumulativeSum()
model_path = '~/Downloads/my_test_model.tflite'
save_model_function_to_tflite(
    cumsummer.add,
    input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec((), tf.float64)],
    path=model_path
)
cumsum_add = load_tflite_model_func(model_path)

assert [cumsum_add(float(i)) for i in range(4)] == [0, 1, 3, 6]
```